# How to send EOF while using ws.send() in javascript using ws npm module

Tags: javascript, websocket, ws

I am using ws npm module to create a websocket client and send big stream of data to websocket server using send() method

I am confused on how can I let the server know that the client has sent all the data and server can start processing i.e how to send EOF from client?

This is my server:

```
import WebSocket = require('ws');
import fs = require('fs');
var port: number = 8989;
var WebSocketServer = WebSocket.Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: port });

wss.on('connection', (ws: WebSocket) => {
    console.log('Web Socket Server Connected');

    ws.on('close', function() {
        console.log("Connection closed by client");
        //ws.close();
    });

     //connection is up, let's add a simple simple event
    ws.on('message', (message: string) => {

        console.log('Data received from client');
        ws.send(message);
        } catch(error) {
            console.log('Connection is closed');
        }
    });

    //send immediatly a feedback to the incoming connection    
    ws.send('Hi there, I am a WebSocket server');
});

console.log(`Server started on port 8989`);
```

This is my client code:

```
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8989/');

      try {
        ws.on('open', function open() {
          console.log('Connected to Server');
          ws.send(streamData);
        });
      } catch (error) {
      }

      ws.on('message', (returnData: Buffer) => {

        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
        console.log('Message from Server: ' + returnData.length);

        console.log('Data received from server');
      });
      ws.on('close', function close() {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
        console.log('Closing connection');
      });

    });
```

I am just sending streamData from client to server and I am echoing the data back from the server to client.

I want to know how to send EOF from client to server, so that the server knows it has received all the data and can do some processing on the data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/HEAD/doc/ws.md have you read this? I think looking at websocket.send and the fin option will give a possible solution for you.

Comment: Will give a read.